# ServiceLoader can't find my implementation

Tags: java, java-module, serviceloader

I'm trying to use ServiceLoader with modules system, the same way as shown in the ***Deploying service providers as modules*** header in the documentation here - [click](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)

I have the following project:

**module tester.client**

```
package tester.client;

import tester.common.Showable;

import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceLoader<Showable> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Showable.class);
        loader.findFirst().orElseThrow(); //throws Exception
    }

}
```

module-info.java

```
import tester.common.Showable;

module tester.client {
    requires tester.common;
    uses Showable;
}
```

**module tester.common**

```
package tester.common;

public interface Showable {
    void show();
}
```

module-info.java

```
module tester.common {
    exports tester.common;
}
```

**module tester.gui**

```
package tester.gui;

import tester.common.Showable;

public class Window implements Showable {
    @Override
    public void show() {

    }
}
```

module-info.java

```
module tester.gui {
    requires tester.common;
    provides tester.common.Showable with tester.gui.Window;
}
```

***THE PROBLEM:***

ServiceLoader doesn't load my implementation.

- tester.client uses Showable
- tester.common exports Showable
- tester.gui provides Showable with Window

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, I guess you miss tester.gui dependency in tester.client.

Comment: @samabcde no, that would be a design flaw: _It is strongly recommended that the module does not export the package containing the service provider._

Comment: I followed what you have in the post, without changing any line of code. To clarify, what I mean is maven dependency.

Comment: @samabcde i don't use maven modules, just java jigsaw ones (as stated in tags)

Comment: Then I think there is something missing for the class path / module path. Please post the java command you are running.

Comment: @samabcde I'm executing the app through Intellij IDEA, here's the exact command it executes: `C:\Java\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=57086:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p C:\Users\wikto\IdeaProjects\ModulesTest\out\production\tester.client;C:\Users\wikto\IdeaProjects\ModulesTest\out\production\tester.common -m tester.client/tester.client.Main`

Comment: You need module path (-p) for "C:\Users\wikto\IdeaProjects\ModulesTest\out\production\tester.gui;"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233449/discussion-between-wiktor-and-samabcde).

Comment: The `-p` option specifies where to resolve modules, but that doesn’t imply that all of them will be loaded. You specified `tester.client` with `-m` and its only dependency is `tester.common`. To ensure that additional modules, i.e. `tester.gui`, get loaded, you need to specify `--add-modules`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem is IDE-specific. As my IDE (Intellij IDEA) has its own additional modules system, I needed to add `tester.gui` module as a dependency of `tester.client` module.

Solution provided by [@samabcde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7928721/samabcde)